# What have designers said for why they made worn items fireproof?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, equipment, designer-reasons

When playing 5e, most of, if not all of the fire spells I've seen say that "a flammable item ignites if not being worn or carried." This makes all items basically fireproof when being worn or carried. I could technically clothe a character in paper and it'd never catch on fire.

What have the designers said were their intentions behind why we have this rule? Please cite their own words on the subject for evidence.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74956/discussion-on-question-by-thatguy-what-have-designers-said-for-why-they-made-wor).

Comment: [Per meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7811/how-should-we-handle-this-fireproof-worn-items-question), answers not citing developer commentary will be deleted.

Comment: @mxyzplk this is the second question like this I have run across since I started using rpg-se and I am starting to feel like these types of questions are inappropriate. Asking "are there designer reasons and if so post them" seems reasonable, but saying I only want answers from designers this seems like the wrong medium and the players should be referred to their respective games FAQ or something like Jeremy Crawfords twitter in the case of 5e. Not being able to answer "no the designers haven't said as far as anyone here knows" seems overly restrictive and reduces the potential value of the Q.

Comment: That's probably something to discuss on the linked meta.

Comment: @Duck related: [Are questions about rule intent on topic?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7964/are-questions-about-rule-intent-on-topic)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [designer reason questions are off-topic](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7968/23064)

Comment: @daze413 While we agreed about that on meta, the last bullet says "Refrain from any campaign to root out and close old questions. (It's unnecessary as churn will get us there, and we should stay open to the possibility that in a few weeks someone comes along with a brilliant perspective/solution that nobody engaged in the last meta thought of.)" - weeks have passed, but I'm not sure we should be doing this.

Comment: @HellSaint Oh, I wasn't campaigning, I was cleaning my favourited questions and found this, so here we are.

Comment: @daze413 I mentioned that but I've voted for closing as well, just to clarify. I just don't know if mxyzplk meant that we shouldn't be flagging/closing these old questions or literally just that we shouldn't be rallying for them.

Comment: I think the primary idea was that we shouldn't try to find and close every old designer-reasons question en masse, but I don't see anything wrong with closing the ones we do come across.