# Is there any logical reason that worn or carried objects don’t take damage from AoE spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, area-of-effect

Objects don’t take damage when their wearer/carrier does, but is there any logical reason for this? In fact,

> The fire spreads around corners.

If the fire spreads around corners, that means that it would surround you (and all your equipment).
So, why wouldn’t it damage objects that are being worn or carried?

Comment: Is this a [designer intent](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7964/are-questions-about-rule-intent-on-topic) question?

Comment: Or is this a duplicate of [What are the implications on making worn items not fire proof in 5e?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/121224/what-are-the-implications-on-making-worn-items-not-fire-proof-in-dd-5e)

Comment: Also, remember this is magical fire physics/logic has already been thrown out the window

Comment: @NautArch _reasons_, not _implications_. So the former.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [Designer Reasons](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7964/are-questions-about-rule-intent-on-topic) are off topic.

Comment: The things that are off-topic are:                                                                    Computer RPGs or MMOs - for those, see gaming.stackexchange.com
Card games, TCGs, miniatures games, or board games - for those, see boardgames.stackexchange.com
Recommendations for RPGs to play - for those, use an RPG discussion forum

Comment: MrHiTech please see [the RPG.SE meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7964/22566).

Comment: I don't think this is a design question as written; I think they're asking about in-universe logic.  It asks if there is a "logical reason", which I think just has the simple answer of, "No."

Comment: @SouthpawHare it's kind of a two-fold issue. The only Reasons for a mechanic can be provided by a Designer  and MrHiTech clarified that this is a designer intent question in the comments above.

Comment: @SouthpawHare if that is the question it should be rephrased to something along the lines of "How do I explain narratively the fact that worn objects do not catch fire from certain spells while non-worn ones do"